# Search Multiple Values through one TextBox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, colors, richtextbox

How to achive searching for multiple values in a textbox.

> Ex: Using~s

[image]

This code can achieve only a single search in the text box.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        string temp = richTextBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.Text = temp;
        while (index < richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text))
        { 
            richTextBox1.Find(textBox1.Text, index, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
            index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, index) + 1;
        }
        this.timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: What is the `richTextBox1` component type?

Comment: @Michalor: obviously a `RichTextBox` or it wouldn't have those methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845267/14171304

Comment: Can Anyone tell me how to achieve different colours for each different words?

Comment: [How to highlight a word or phrase with a color different from all the other selections in a RichTextBox text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012582/7444103)

Comment: For _different colours for each different words_, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/5438626) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980957/5438626) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the split keyword.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;
            string temp = richTextBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.Text="";
            richTextBox1.Text = temp;
            this.timer1.Start();
            string[] names = textBox1.Text.Split('~');
            int count = 0;
                while (index < richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(names[0]))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Find(names[0], index, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(names[0], index) + 1;
                count++;
                }

                int count2 = 0;
                while (index < richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(names[1]))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Find(names[1], index, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(names[1], index) + 1;
                    count2++;
                }
       }
```